# Mapping a dictionary including interval data

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
d = {'col1':['a','c','b','q','w','f','h','v','t','y'],
     'col2':[1,3,33,7,5,8,2,3,5,0]}
    df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I bin the second column as

```
df['col3'] = pd.cut(x=df['col2'], bins=[-0.001,2.25,4,6.5,33])
```

Now I wish to make a new column from `col3` such that each bracket is represented by a string. The outcome should look like

```
 col1  col2            col3     col4
0    a     1  (-0.001, 2.25]  range 1
1    c     3     (2.25, 4.0]  range 2
2    b    33     (6.5, 33.0]  range 4
3    q     7     (6.5, 33.0]  range 4
4    w     5      (4.0, 6.5]  range 3
5    f     8     (6.5, 33.0]  range 4
6    h     2  (-0.001, 2.25]  range 1
7    v     3     (2.25, 4.0]  range 2
8    t     5      (4.0, 6.5]  range 3
9    y     0  (-0.001, 2.25]  range 1
```

I was thinking to make a dictionary as

```
di = {(-0.001, 2.25]: "range 1", (2.25, 4.0]: "range 2", (4.0, 6.5]: "range 3", (6.5, 33.0]: "range 4"}
```

and use

```
df['col4'] = df['col3'].map(di)
```

Yet above dictionary is wrong as one can not express the intervals as such in a dictionary. So I wonder how can I make mapping on interval data?

Comment: Instead of using `cut`, use `pd.qcut(df[col], 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `col3` is an **ordered** `categorical` column, use [`Series.cat.codes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html):

```
In [306]: df['col4'] = 'range ' + (df.col3.cat.codes + 1).astype(str)

In [307]: df
Out[307]: 
  col1  col2            col3     col4
0    a     1  (-0.001, 2.25]  range 1
1    c     3     (2.25, 4.0]  range 2
2    b    33     (6.5, 33.0]  range 4
3    q     7     (6.5, 33.0]  range 4
4    w     5      (4.0, 6.5]  range 3
5    f     8     (6.5, 33.0]  range 4
6    h     2  (-0.001, 2.25]  range 1
7    v     3     (2.25, 4.0]  range 2
8    t     5      (4.0, 6.5]  range 3
9    y     0  (-0.001, 2.25]  range 1
```

Comment: Brilliant! just want to add that `col3` is an **ordered** categorical column :-).

Answer (score 1):

Just try pass the `labels`

```
df['col3'] = pd.cut(x=df['col2'], bins=[-0.001,2.25,4,6.5,33],labels =['range ' + str(x)for x in range(1,5)])
df
Out[168]: 
  col1  col2     col3
0    a     1  range 1
1    c     3  range 2
2    b    33  range 4
3    q     7  range 4
4    w     5  range 3
5    f     8  range 4
6    h     2  range 1
7    v     3  range 2
8    t     5  range 3
9    y     0  range 1
```